# Why is my og:image not working?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, debugging, facebook-graph-api

I am using `Wordpress` and `WP Yoast SEO plugin` and I want to get an image if I post my link on Facebook. That's not happening and I don't know why. I have used Facebook's debugger tool and I got this:

`The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'article:publisher'`

Why is this? It does not say a thing about my image.... Besides, I can see it in the fetched results on Facebook debugger, so that must not be a problem either. The article:publisher was wrapped in single quotes like this: `'` and I changed it to `"`, but it still gives me the same problem.

This is the scraped url:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="blabla">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="blablablbla">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://blablablblabla">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="blablablabala">
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/pages/blbalblbalab">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://blblalblba.png">
```

And this the ruwe open graph document information

```
Metatag:    <meta property="og:locale" content="blabla" />
Metatag:    <meta property="og:type" content="blbalbae" />
Metatag:    <meta property="og:title" content="blablbla" />
Metatag:    <meta property="og:url" content="http://blablbal.com/" />
Metatag:    <meta property="og:site_name" content="blblablba" />
Metatag:    <meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/pages/blblbalab" />
Metatag:    <meta property="og:image" content="http://blbalblab.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing the image to an image that is exactly 200x200...

Damn it, why does Facebook not say that in the `debugger tool`? Anyhow, it's solved.